# Saving iPhone data storage by moving Notes to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, memory, notes.app

Can I save data storage space on my iPhone by moving Notes folders from On My iPhone to iCloud, if possible, how?

Comment: What do you mean by memory?

Comment: if the notes contain **just text** then deleting or moving them will not free up enough space for the phone to even notice. If you need to free space first look at images and videos. Also any apps you don't use any more.

Answer (score 0):

The internal storage on your phone can get used with notes - especially if there are attachments, but it’s not the normal culprit for running out of space.

From settings app - go to general and then go to iPhone storage. (Leave it running for about 10 minutes connected to power if possible)

You can save some space if notes are saved to iCloud and you run out of storage.

Comment: Thank you. But I can see in the storage manager in Settings that I have 7G of notes!! Many of them have web links, some have pictures. I moved some folders to the iCloud, but there was no change in the space used. Do I then need to unsync my notes? How do I do that?

Comment: Putting them in iCloud doesn't mean the iOS will purge them locally.  If it didn't cache locally, people would just whine about how slow it was when it had to go to the internet to retrieve anything at all.

Comment: If you have a Mac signed into iCloud you can sync the notes to your Mac. Then turn off syncing on your phone and remove the things you don't need *on your phone* but need to otherwise hold on to on your Mac.